# Sqlite: if reference not used then delete, else update

Tags: sqlite, case

I have a `user` table with `user_id` as `primary key`

```
user_id | name   | email           | deleted
1       | John   | john@gmail.com  | NULL
```

Field `user_id` is used like reference in some other tables.

Now, when I want to delete the user, I would like to `delete` the row if is not used in some other tables or `update` (mark `users.deleted=1`) if used

In this moment I do it from 2 sequences, but I would like to do it from one.

I've try with CASE but no chance... said "Near CASE syntax error"

```
CASE 
WHEN (SELECT count(resp_user_id) AS counter FROM equip WHERE user_id = 1)  > 0
  THEN (UPDATE users SET deleted = 1 WHERE user_id=1)
  ELSE (DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=1) 
END
```

What did I write wrong?

Comment: In the other tables use foreign keys and then you get an error when you try to delete a user referenced in the other tables

Comment: I don't want with foreign keys. I would like to handle the errors by myself.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an embedded database, i.e., it is designed to be used together with a 'real' programming language.

There is no such logic in SQLite itself. You have to write the logic in your program, and use multiple SQL statements:

```py
cursor = db.execute("SELECT resp_user_id AS counter FROM equip WHERE user_id = ?", [id])
if not cursor.empty:
    db.execute("UPDATE users SET deleted = 1 WHERE user_id = ?", [id])
else:
    db.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", [id])
```

To make the accesses atomic, wrap them into a transaction.

Comment: ok, 2 sentences then :) how can I do it with a transaction if in between i must take a decision?

Comment: The `if` is a decision. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not in one sequence, but in a secured way the command can be:

```
begin transaction; 
delete from users where user_id=1 and ((select count(resp_user_id) from equip where resp_user_id = 1) = 0); 
update users set deleted = 1 where user_id=1 and ((select count(resp_user_id) from equip where resp_user_id = 1) > 0); 
end transaction;
```